# Identity scaffolding with AppplicationDbContext

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

ASP.NET Core 2.x now hides the Identity pages and logic inside of a library. In order to extend the `IdentityUser` entity with new properties and add UI and logic to deal with those new properties, we now get to run the "Identity scaffolder" (under MyProject -> Add -> New scaffolded item).  Unfortunately, [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x) are incomplete at best and, in more than a few instance, flat out wrong.

I'm struggling to figure out how to wrestle the scaffolder and the resultant code to achieve what I would assume is a pretty standard use case:

1. I'm starting with a new ASP.NET Core MVC app
2. I want to extend `IdentityUser` with my own properties. Since this involves creating an inherited class, I want the name of that new class to be `ApplicationUser`.
3. I want to scaffold the Identity pages I need to fiddle with (Login, Register, Manage, etc.)
4. **I want to use the existing `ApplicationDbContext`**

My problem is that, reading the docs and playing with the Identity scaffolder, I can't figure out how to get the scaffolder to let me extend `IdentityUser` *and* keep using the existing `ApplicationDbContext`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After staring at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x) and playing with the scaffolder and the resultant code, I think I've figure out most of it.

1. Start with a new ASP.NET Core Web Application, with "Individual user accounts" authentication. Apparently, it doesn't really matter whether you start with a "Web Application" (i.e. Razor Pages) or "Web Application (Model-View-Controller)" (i.e. MVC).  In the end, the Identity pages will be Razor Pages, but they function just fine within an MVC app.
2. Build the solution. I'm not sure if this is necessary, but it doesn't hurt...
3. Before you go any farther, **make sure you like your DB connection string** (in appsettings.json). In the Package Manager Console, enter the command **update-database**.  This apparently updates the ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs file to include the initial migration that you got from the project template. If you skip this step then, when you add your first migration, it will include all of the migration steps you already have in 00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema.cs. Also, this step is apparently needed in order for the scaffolder to recognize the existing `ApplicationDbContext`.
4. Right-click the project and select **Add -> New scaffolded item**; Select the **Identity** item type
5. Specify your existing _Layout.cshtml and select the pages you want to scaffold
6. Next to Data context class, click the drop-down arrow and select the existing `ApplicationDbContext`
7. Click the Add button to perform the scaffolding.

At this point, your project is wired up to the existing `ApplicationDbContext` and `IdentityUser` classes.  Now, you can extend `IdentityUser` and wire up the Identity pages to use the new, extended entity:

Add a new `ApplicationUser` class that inherits from `IdentityUser`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
}
```

Add the new `ApplicationUser` entity to the `ApplicationDbContext` class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Replace all instances of `<IdentityUser>` with `<ApplicationUser>`.  This means that you will change startup.cs to call `services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()`, and you will replace all of the references to `SigninManager` and `UserManager` to specify the new `<ApplicationUser>` Type parameter.

Whew... now, you can go into things like Register.cshtml.cs and create (or fetch) a new `ApplicationUser` rather than an `IdentityUser`, and all of the plumbing will be wired up to `ApplicationUser`.  For example, the code in Register.cshtml.cs might look like this:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser {
    UserName = Input.Email,
    Email = Input.Email,
    Nickname = Input.Nickname // New property
};
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, without Identity, `ApplicationDbContext` inherits from `DbContext`.

I have a solution with four projects. `WEB`, `WebAPI`, `DATA` and `ENTITIES`.

I have a single `ApplicationDbContext` located in `DATA`  and have modified it to inherit from `IdentityDbContext` e.g.:

`public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>`

Now, `ENTITIES` is where the models (POCOs) are defined.

And, `AppliationDbContext` in `DATA` contains references to these classes and contains the `DbSet<T>` property setter used by EF. The `Person`(aka, `ApplicationUser`) class in `ENTITIES` looks like this:

`public class Person : IdentityUser 
    {
        [PersonalData]
        public string LastName { get; set; }`

In the `WEB` project, with the appropriate references to `DATA` and `ApplicationDContext`, I have only one `services.AddDbContext<T>` dependency reference; then use that context within `AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()` service addition.:

```
         services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

That seemed to do the trick to use only one `DbContext` service. It also extended the `AspNetUsers` table to include the `[PersonalData]` properties I had set in the POCO `Person` model class located within `ENTITIES`.

Now, since 
`<IdentityUser>` has been extended, in my case by `Person`, all references to `IdentityUser` should be updated to reflect that. So `Startup.ConfigureServices` now looks like this:

```
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<Person>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

And, within the UI, to gain access to the properties added by 'Person', references in `~/Identity/Account/Manage/Index.cshtml.cs` need to be updated as well:

```
        private readonly UserManager<Person> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<Person> _signInManager;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

    public IndexModel(
        UserManager<Person> userManager,
        SignInManager<Person> signInManager,
        IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
    }
```

You will have to update the 'InputModel' in `index.cshtml.cs` as well as the 'new up' in `OnGetAsync()` method to map the properties -- similar to how `Email` is handled by the default settings.

And then, finally, there is the `index.cshtml` view file to give access to the UI/razor display.

This should get you on your way with items 1 - 4 in your question.

Comment: Man, that is one well-crafted, detailed answer.  Unfortunately, unless I'm missing something, it's not the answer to the question I thought I was asking.  I'll update the question to clarify that I'm asking specifically about the ASP.NET Core Identity scaffolder and my difficulty figuring out how to scaffold Identity pages while still using my existing `ApplicationDbContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the Right Click on the solution but could not select the ApplicationDbContext. I had to update the Visual Studio to the latest version and install all the latest SDK (.Net Core 3.1). After that it all worked like a charm. Hope it helps someone.