# Scaffold CRUD operations in MVC or Razor pages for my custom IdentityUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-scaffolding

after hours spent on the internet to study a solution I finally decided to question the stackoverflow community.

I have a custom IdentityUser named AppUser:

```
public class AppUser: IdentityUser
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext is defined as follow:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to generate CRUD pages through Visual Studio scaffolding system with option Razor Pages using Entity Framework (CRUD) or MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework in the list of model classes I did not get my AppUser model. Please help to find out where I am missing something.

Thanks,
HPS.

Comment: add yout DbContext class code to questions

Comment: is your question answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51410214/7834019

Comment: @NimaTalebi added ApplicationDbContext as per your request. The link you posted is about scaffolding Identity item.

Comment: @HarpreetParmjitSaini Can you check your database?your database is updated or not after migration and update with your property " name" and "surename"?

Comment: your say ```I did not get my AppUser model``` . where you did not found Appuser model property? are you not found when you trying to access this Appuser model property in your controller?Or failed to update identity user data table with your custom property in DB?please clarify that

Comment: @PritomSarkar yes it is updated. The two fields are present in the db table.

Comment: What happen is the following:
In the Visual Studio I go to "Add New Scoffolded Item" and then select "Razor Pages using Entity Framework (CRUD)" and click "Add".  Then I am prompted to a pop-up where I need to select Model class and in that list I can't find my AppUser. If I remove in the definition of AppUser extension from IdentityUser it appears in the list.

Comment: try to ```public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext```remove AppUser from here

Comment: @HarpreetParmjitSaini then what happened. let me know.

Comment: @PritomSarkar  nothing changes.

Comment: @HarpreetParmjitSaini what did you use to build your project,.Net Core MVC or .net core razor pages which?

Comment: @PritomSarkar i tried both.